# Which Ubuntu version for my old laptop

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, system

i want to try Ubuntu on my 11 year old laptop (Dell).
I don't get the latest system requirements, but maybe you can help me find an older version that i can try.
My favorite would be Ubuntu, but if it isn't going to work i will also try Lubuntu. (Btw: is Lubuntu made by Cannonical, too?)

**My system requirements:**

- DELL Laptop, 64-Bit
- CPU: Intel Celeron CPU 900 @ 2.20GHz
- GPU: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4300
- RAM: 2 GB

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would love to see the requirements of 14.04, too, if possible

Comment: v14.04 is EOL and thus off topic on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: @24601 well my laptop is also very old so ... ;)

Comment: Please click to check whether [Canonical](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?vendors=Dell) has certified your system type for Ubuntu. You may also check [How to install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc)

Comment: Don't use an EOL operating system.  You expose yourself to known, but unpatched security vulnerabilities and you won't get critical bug fixes.

Comment: I used laptops using pentium M to *QA-test* Lubuntu & Xubuntu up to 19.04 (they were single core pentium M) when x86/32-bit was dropped. I'm using a 2009 dell desktop right now and using Lubuntu *hirsute* (what will be 21.04 when it's released), so unless you're only going to use it off-line & thus security doesn't matter; I'd avoid using EOL/unsupported/unpatched software online (and I sure don't see the need).   I wouldn't use main Ubuntu (GNOME requires more resources), but a *lighter* flavor.   (the oldest machine I booted Lubuntu 18.04.5 on during *testing* in August 2020 was from 2003)

Comment: @Nmath am I wrong or can i get updates for 14.04 while using the ESM program?

Comment: @guiverc I would prefer using Ubuntu because of Cannonical, I made very bad experiences with community driven Linux versions, like Linux Mint.

Comment: I consider official ubuntu flavors, downloaded from ubuntu.com (ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) as a very different animal to Linux Mint.  All Ubuntu *flavors* go through the same procedure as Ubuntu (same SRU rules apply as main Ubuntu), we are runtime *adjustment* free (unlike Linux Mint) and thus don't have the attack-vectors that Mint has, our packages are built on the same infrastructure (launchpad) as Ubuntu; it's just different GUI & a shorter support period (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ note: 5 years for Canonical & 3 years for Community)

Comment: Yes you can get updated packages if you enable ESM (https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) however most support sites don't allow ESM releases, however paid support is available if you wish (Ubuntu Advantage).  Also note only 'main' packages are supported for ESM (refer my prior note for community/flavor packages, so it'll depend what you want to use the system for as to how safe/useful it is, as 'universe' packages support ended in 2017-April for 14.04/trusty; though I'm aware of one package that was patched a few days into 2017-May).

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the info! I decided myself to use 14.04 and it works great so far :)

Comment: No, you do not get all updates with ESM. You only get updates deemed critical in the `main` repository. This does not include the majority of software on a typical desktop installation. And you only get these updates if you actually subscribe to ESM. ESM is not really for desktop users and it's definitely not for new installations. The purpose of ESM is to provide extended maintenance to organizations running servers to give them additional time to migrate. Under ESM you also receive no community support. If you have an issue you need help with, you have to pay Canonical for support.

Comment: @Nmath still asking is always worth a try :)

Comment: Hope you're offline, and not using a browser (you'll need to back-port the patches yourself, given they're not being done for you, and many haven't for a long time now).